# Attaching/Printing an image onto metal

Tags: print-design, images, metal

I have a 507mm x 510.5mm metal sheet that I want to put a design onto. The design is rather complicated and I have no talent so painting is not an option. I'm looking for something similar to what this guy has done on the side panel of his computer case: [image: Something like this]

**BUT** I want the image to cover the entire panel and I don't want to pay through the nose for it. What options are there for doing this? I don't mind printing onto plastics or paper and then laminating it or something "hacky" like that. Which techniques and tricks are the cheapest and have the best results? Please comment anything you can think of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be printed on UV Flatbed Printer. If you can find near you who deals in billboards, signage etc. Nowadays, most of them have UV flatbed Printers which are used to print on metals, sun-board, ply board, glass, acrylic etc.

[Youtube link for a demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nbotNT9BKRs)

[image]

Comment: It seems to be very expensive though.

Comment: No, it isn't, at my place (in India) It cost me approx 90 Rupees (about 1.25 $) per Sq. ft. We always print in a lot, but for small job like this, they could charge a bit more.

here's a [sample](https://scontent-yyz1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xaf1/t31.0-8/11148530_878432518883767_5865962435797472448_o.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The cheapest is to print in a self adhesive paper. You can either buy a sheet on a copy center, or print the design there, and just cutting it. Obviously you will not see any metalic finish on the image.

There are some other materials, like adhesive vinyl and there is one transparent called mylar, that is used for stickers but I am not sure if it can be printed in a copy center with a láser print for example.

The "pro" way to do it on this days is hydrographics.

Answer (score 0):

Vinyl sticker is best for this purpose. But you need to remove the part from the CPU. It should not be so difficult. Use hair dryer for quick drying. I came across this youtube video of vinyl wrap. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l_ZhrrJyLUU